# SwiftUI: Drag WINDOW with Left Mouse Button down on the view

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a view with Image in it.

```
@SceneBuilder
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ImageView()
    }
}
```

ImageView is just an image:

```
struct ImageView: View  {
    var body: some View {
        Image(.logo)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    }
}
```

How to drag WINDOW by click on the `ImageView` with left mouse button?

Just with the same way like we dragging window by click on the window Header/ Title / Safe area zone.

MacOs, SwiftUI 3

Google did show nothing useful

Comment: `@SceneBuilder` is new thing or a custom code? I have not seen it.

Comment: @swiftPunk it's native thing https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/06/23/what-is-new-in-swiftui/ , up from swiftUI 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

usage:

```
Text("drag wnd with me")
    .dragWndWithClick()
```

Back code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@available(OSX 11.0, *)
extension View {
    func dragWndWithClick() -> some View {
        self.overlay(DragWndView())
    }
}

struct DragWndView: View {
    let test: Bool
    
    init(test: Bool = false) {
        self.test = test
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ( test ? Color.green : Color.clickableAlpha )
            .overlay( DragWndNSRepr() )
    }
}

///////////////
///HELPERS
///////////////

fileprivate struct DragWndNSRepr: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        return DragWndNSView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) { }
}

fileprivate class DragWndNSView: NSView {
    override public func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        window?.performDrag(with: event)
    }
}

@available(OSX 10.15, *)
public extension Color {
    init(hex: UInt32) {
        self.init(
            red:       Double((hex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            green:     Double((hex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            blue:      Double(hex & 0xFF) / 256.0
        )
    }
    
    init(rgbaHex: UInt32) {
        self.init(
            red:      Double((rgbaHex >> 24) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            green:    Double((rgbaHex >> 16) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            blue:     Double((rgbaHex >> 8) & 0xFF) / 256.0,
            opacity:  Double(rgbaHex & 0xFF) / 256.0
        )
    }
}

@available(OSX 10.15, *)
public extension Color {
    static var clickableAlpha: Color { get { return Color(rgbaHex: 0x01010101) } }
}
```

Comment: You defined a class called as App!!!, but how? it is impossible. It is unclear how actually be your answer usable or even works. You may show the working example to make unclear part be clear.

Comment: It is steal unclear how you would use your class.

Comment: posted better solution. Deleted all old comments

Comment: I think it would make issue to Drag Gesture in SwiftUI, may you get issue for tap button or slider or even drag shapes in view.

Comment: yep, it can be. Only you need is to do ZStack and apply this modifier only on background layer and no issues for buttons or gestures located in the front layer :)